# The set of integral elements form a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, integral-extensions

Let $A \subset B$ be two rings.
I know that an element $x \in B$ is integral over $A$ iff $A[x]$ is contained in a finitely generated $A$-module $T \subset B$.
I also know that if $b_1,...,b_n$ are integral over $A$ then $A[b_1,...,b_n]$ is a finitely generated $A$-module.

Why does these imply that the set of elements of $B$ that are integral over $A$ form a ring?

Comment: See for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608875/ring-of-integral-elements-of-a-commutative-ring).

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b$ be two elements of $B$ integral over A. Your second assertion implies that $a\in{}M, b\in{}N$ which are both finitelly generated submodules of $B$. Then $MN=\{\sum{}a_ib_j,  a_i\in{}M,b_j\in{}N\}$ is a finitelly generated submodule of $B$. Notice that $MN$ contains both $a+b$ and $ab$ and the conclusion follows...

Note that you are taking the $x$-subalgebra generated by $x$  (I mean $A[x]$) but you really need a finitely generated submodule of $A$ (let's say $M$) such that $xM\subset{}M$. Since Dedekind's proof uses this inclusion to work with Cramer's rule it is this essential property that's needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Shouldn't it be simpler than that though?

Comment: @roi_saumon: How much easier could it possibly get?

Comment: I think it is pretty straightforward to prove that $MN$ is a finitely generated submodule, so not sure what would be an even shorter proof